# How to Fetch the length of the column using a Instead of Trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, check-constraints

I am trying to fetch the length of a particular column in Instead of Trigger using LEN() function. I want to fetch the length of a column from inserted table and then compare the length using if else so that I can do the required actions. Here is what I am doing:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_firstNameLength_signupTable]
ON [dbo].[signup_table]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Declare @length varchar(50)
    select  @length = i.first_name from inserted i where i.first_name != null
    if (LEN(@length) > 50)
    Raiserror('Invalid Firstname. Please try again', 16, 1)
    else
    insert into signup_table(first_name, surname, mobile_number, email_address, salt, password)
    select first_name, surname, mobile_number, email_address, salt, password from inserted
END
```

or Should I user CHECK  CONSTRAINT?
I am open to suggestions. So feel free to suggest How I can achieve it in a better way. TIA... :)

Comment: Why is trigger *or* check constraint in the picture here? `(n)varchar` columns arlready come with a free maximum length built in.

Comment: Here I have used trigger because I want to check the length of the data before it is being inserted into my table and if the length is greater than the data size then display the message else insert into the table. Apart from Instead of trigger is there any other way I can do so? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Use check constraint.

Comment: @DeanSavović I tried but couldn't achieve it. Can you show with an example?

Comment: What's not clear is - why is the right solution not `CREATE TABLE signup_table ( ..., first_name varchar(50), ...);` - why is not just declaring the column maximum length sufficient?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here? `select @length = i.first_name from inserted i` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because I want to limit the user input to 50 characters only. That is my requirement at the moment. I don't want the users to enter the chunks of data in the database.

Comment: Yes, so if you declare the column as `varchar(50)`, there's **no** possibility of a longer value being inserted. As it stands, you're having to declare your column with a longer length, e.g. `varchar(255)` or `varchar(max)`, to even *allow* the possibility of a longer insert to happen, to even be able to *get* to the point of a trigger or check constraint to prevent it. Why do you want to *do more work* than using the built in length?

Comment: I prefer to check user input in the UI, not in the database. If the user can enter a name longer than 50 char, he might get frustrated, when the input is rejected.

Comment: @Peter Yes you are right, it is best practice to do it at Frontend but apparently that is not my concern at the moment. I am just testing my database. So that's why I am checking the data length at database level considering the case that if anyhow front end validations fail.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because I want to display my own message rather then by default message printed by SQL SERVER at the moment it is showing up Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated. which is not what I want.

Comment: Then that is a *key* part of the question since you cannot control the error message through a check constraint either. Please *edit* that into your question, alongside any other *requirements*. I.e. as others have pointed out, triggers run once per statement, so for a multi-row insert, how should the trigger act if *some* rows violate your requirement and others do not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. Here I am only considering for single row insertion. Only one row will be inserted. What you recommend that should I handle the error message generated by SQL or just amend the trigger?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, mate. I did it by handling the exception. That was super easy. I made it complex by creating a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.signup_table
ADD CONSTRAINT
CK_signup_table_first_name CHECK (len(first_name) <= 50)
```